# does heirloom-mailx need sendmail?

Tags: mail, sendmail

I installed the `heirloom-mailx` package and tried to use `mailx` to send an email:

```
$ echo "heirloom mailx works!" | mailx -s "Server mail" me@example.org
```

However the operation did not succeed:

```
Cannot start "/usr/sbin/sendmail": executable not found (adjust *sendmail* variable)
"/root/dead.letter" 6/136
... message not sent
```

Am I expected to install `sendmail` in order to use `heirloom-mailx`?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I expected to install sendmail in order to use heirloom-mailx?

No, but you need a mail service. `hierloom-mailx` can be set up to use [SMTP](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html):

> Supports SMTP to send messages directly to a remote server. A local sendmail interface setup is thus not necessary. In combination with OpenSSL or NSS, both the STARTTLS method and SMTPS can be used. SMTP AUTH is also supported.

You will need to configure heirloom-mailx though.

---

Using SMTP

```
mailx -v -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" \
-S smtp=smtp://smtp.server.com
-S from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)" \
$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

---

Using gmail:

```
mailx -v -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 \
-S from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)" \
-S smtp-auth-user=$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS \
-S smtp-auth-password=$EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S nss-config-dir=~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/ \
$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

[Source](https://www.systutorials.com/1411/sending-email-from-mailx-command-in-linux-using-gmails-smtp/)

Comment: How can I tell `mailx` not to use `/usr/sbin/sendmail`? There is little documentation on how to configure heirloom-mailx. What is weird is that In a different server I installed `mailutils` and then did purge it. Now `mailx` works because there is a `sendmail` in `/usr/sbin`. Perhaps I need it.

Comment: @Asarluhi nope. See the 2 examples ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved installing `sendmail`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Once `sendmail` was installed, I edited `/etc/hosts` as follows, adding a valid domain:

```
127.0.1.1  ubuntu  example.org
```

Then I used the following command to reconfigure sendmail:

```
$ sendmailconfig
```

Now I am able to send emails from my server.